# 'Provide Value....' exception on static resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, staticresource

Im getting this exception:

`'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '13' and line position '6'.`

when i attempt to run the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Application.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:me="clr-namespace:WPF_Application"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="me:ExampleBusinessObject" x:Key="BusinessObjectTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding BusinessObjects}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BusinessObjectTemplate}"/>
</Window>
```

From what i can tell, this is normally caused by thing the static resource extension is pointing to not being available, but as far as im aware the template should be available at that point.

Comment: Does the issue go away if `DataType` if removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest removing the datatype as mentioned above or removing the itemtemplate from the itemscontrol.

The reason your getting this error is your providing 2 conflicting bits of information. By setting the datatype you are telling WPF to use this datatemplate whenever the type of object is ExampleBusinessObject. By setting the ItemTemplate your are telling WPF to use this datatemplate at all times. Use one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

XAML pretends to be xml, but order ends up mattering sometimes when it shouldn't.  Put the DataType after the x:key.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BusinessObjectTemplate" DataType="me:ExampleBusinessObject">
```